# Как прочитать объект из потока

Tags: java

Есть задание: `Многопоточный  клиент-сервер`.

На сервере запущено два потока, один читает, другой отправляет сообщения.

Читающий поток сохраняет сообщения в блокирующую очередь.

Никак не получается понять как можно сохранить обьект сообщения в эту очередь?

```
public class Server implements Serializable  {

    public static final int PORT = 8099;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayBlockingQueue<Message> messagesPool;
        ExecutorService cachedPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Set<Socket> clients = null;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Сервер запущен");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

        while (!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.print((clientSocket.isConnected() ? "Соединение установлено " : " Не удалось соедениться"));
            assert false;
            boolean added = clients.add(clientSocket);
            if (added) System.out.println(clientSocket + " Добавлен !");
            if (clientSocket.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println(clientSocket + " отключился!");
                clients.remove(clientSocket);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ServerReader implements Runnable, Serializable  {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    ArrayBlockingQueue<Message> messagesPool;
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;

    public ServerReader(ServerSocket serverSocket, ArrayBlockingQueue<Message> messagesPool, ObjectInputStream objectInputStream) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
        this.messagesPool = messagesPool;
        this.objectInputStream = objectInputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        messagesPool = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);
        while(!serverSocket.isClosed()){
//            непонятно.

        }
    }
}
```

Извиняюсь, если затронул большие умы таким вопросом, только учусь.

Comment: Добавлять через метод add(). Думаю вопрос у вас немного другой. Опишите подробнее что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-objectinputstream-readobject-method